# LetsEncrypt - ACMESharp client challenge in pending state for over an hour

Tags: rest, powershell, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

Decided to try the Letsencrypt service recently.
I'm using the Windows Powershell client found here - https://github.com/ebekker/ACMESharp

Following the quickstart instructions here - https://github.com/ebekker/ACMESharp/wiki/Quick-Start - I managed to get to Step 6b of the manual http authentication process, but when I check the status of the request with the `Update-ACMEIdentifier dns1 -ChallengeType http-01` command, the challenge request remains in a pending state:

```
IdentifierPart : ACMESharp.Messages.IdentifierPart
IdentifierType : dns
Identifier     : www.example.com
Uri            : https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/#myhash
Status         : pending
Expires        : 16/02/2016 00:00:00
Challenges     : {manual, , }
Combinations   : {1, 0, 2}
```

I've been checking on the status every 10 minutes for the past hour, but it's still pending. The quickstart instructions suggest that the process should take between a few seconds, and a few minutes.

Is this an ACME server issue, or an uninformative error response?

Comment: I ran into this myself on a development local machine (that is Internet accessible) I used for testing. Same thing - request stayed in `pending` mode. I then ran through the same procedure on my live Web Server and had no problems. If things are working the request should validate within a few minutes at most.  Not sure what the difference is exactly, except the local machine is using port forwarding and only has port 80 and 443 open to the Internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The challenge you have requested is probably not in a pending but the first one is. You will see there are three possible challenges (dns, tns and http). If you output the individual challenges you will probably see the the http challenge has been validated. Try:

(Update-ACMEIdentifier dns1 -ChallengeType http-01).Challenges

To list the details of all three challenges including the individual statuses.